# See coordinates of the cursor in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Given that there is an empty document in Illustrator CS5, is there a way to see what it the current X and Y coordinates of the point at which the cursor is pointing at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to see the coordinates one just needs to **hold down the shift** key while hovering the point.